# Finding Distribution Given Conditional Distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X,Y$ are random variables.

Suppose that $(X | Y=y) \sim B(2,e^{-y})$ and that $Y \sim E(1)$.

Find the distribution of $X$.

---

I'm really struggling with this. Here's what I'm doing:

Let $f_Y(y)=e^{-y}$ be the density of $Y$.

I define $g(Y):=\textbf{P}(X = k | Y = y)$.

Then
\begin{align}
\textbf{P}(X=k) &= \textbf{E}g(Y) \\
&= \int_0^\infty g(y)f_Y(y) dy \\
&= \int_0^\infty{2 \choose k} e^{-k(y+1)}(1 - e^{-y})^{2-k} dy \\
&= 0 \tag{for k=0,1,2}
\end{align}

But this makes no sense at all.

Any advice?

Comment: Why $=0$? That the integral of a positive function should be zero, indeed "this makes no sense at all"...

Comment: $=0$ by positive integrand?? Btw, note that $e^{-k(y+1)}$ must be interchanged with $e^{-(k+1)y}$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that is nonsense.  Try this:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=k) ~&=~ \int_0^\infty\mathsf P(X=k\mid Y=y)\,\mathsf P(Y=y)\operatorname d y\\[1ex] &=~ \int_0^\infty \binom{2}{k}e^{-ky}(1-e^{-y})^{2-k}\cdot e^{-y}~\mathbf 1_{k\in \{0,1,2\}}\operatorname d y\\[1ex] &=~ \int_0^\infty \binom 2ke^{-3y}(e^y-1)^{2-k}~\mathbf 1_{k\in \{0,1,2\}}\operatorname d y \\[1ex] &=  \int_0^\infty \left(\begin{cases} e^{-y}-2e^{-2y}+e^{-3y} &:& k=0 \\ 2e^{-2y}-2e^{-3y}&:& k=1\\ e^{-3y} &:& k=2 \\ 0 &:& \text{other}\end{cases}\right)\operatorname d y\\[2ex] &~\vdots\\[2ex] &\neq 0~\mathbf 1_{k\in \{0,1,2\}}\end{align}$$

What it actually equals is quite interesting.